# Remove space between two grid - Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, grid

I would like to remove the space between two grid. I tried the padx and y and sticky but it didn't work for me. Do you have an idea to remove this space ? It's very basic tkinter, it's just to expose my problem.

Thanks you,

```
    import pandas as pd
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter.ttk  import * 

    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2, 4, 8, 0],[1,2, 0, 0, 0],[1,10, 2, 1, 8]],columns=['A','B','C','D','E'],index=['year', 'month','ok'])


    class Timer: 
        def __init__(self, parent,df):
            #print(df)
            # variable storing time
            # label displaying time
            r,c = df.shape
            size_standard = 10
            self.label = tk.Label(root,width=size_standard)
            self.label.pack()

            e = tk.Entry(self.label,justify='center',width=size_standard)
            e.config({"background": '#dcf1fc'})
            e.insert(0, 'vl')
            e.grid(row=0, column=1,padx=0,pady=0)

            e = tk.Entry(self.label,justify='center',width=size_standard)
            e.config({"background": '#dcf1fc'})
            e.insert(0, 'vll')
            e.grid(row=0, column=2)


    root = tk.Tk()
    timer = Timer(root,df)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also provide a picture example?

Comment: I added it in my original post

Comment: You question has nothing to do with dataframes per se, so get rid of it and provide a [mre] with respect to just what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white area in your screenshot is the area reserved for the highlight ring - the part of the UI that shows which widget has the keyboard focus. The simplest solution is to remove the ring, though the user then loses the ability to easily see which widget has focus.

```
e.configure(highlightthickness=0)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your tip. I used your method and bd=0 
<      e = tk.Entry(self.label,justify='center',width=size_standard,bd=0)
        e.config({"background": '#dcf1fc'},highlightthickness=0)>

Comment: I changed the size of the name of columns, I have again the space between the cell. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: @FloCp That question has nothing to do with the original question or this answer.

Answer (score -1):

The entrys have a border. If you specify border thickness=0 the gap will disappear:

```
e.config(bd=0)
```